# Express.js disable console color

Tags: node.js, express

When starting an Express webapp from Eclipse, output in console has strange characters:

```
[90mGET / [32m200 [90m310ms - 162b[0m
```

I guess they are "color" characters: when running express from a terminal, output is colorful.

How to disable color output from Express?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your own format instead of dev.
refer this:
http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the 'tiny' logging format is similar to the (colored) 'dev' format:

```
app.use(express.logger('tiny'));
```